# Taking strings of a specific length from an array

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, nsarray, enumeration

I have this code to read in a text file, with words separated by newlines. What I want to do is read all the words into an array and then pick all the six-letter words from that array.

I have this code below, but it seems to be generating an error from within the for loop.

Also, after reading in the text file, do I have to release it?

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"newdict" ofType:@"txt"];

NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

NSArray* allLinedStrings = [content componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];

int wordcount = [allLinedStrings count];
int i;
NSMutableArray* sixLetterWords;

for( i = 0 ; i < wordcount ; i++)
{
    NSString* word = [allLinedStrings objectAtIndex: i];
    if (StrLength(word) == 6)
        [sixLetterWords addObject:word];
}
```

Comment: For future questions, it's a good idea to give specific error messages, instead of trying to make people guess what the error you are seeing is, and on what line.

Comment: Will put that in mind next time, thank you very much.:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better options than a for loop are [fast enumeration](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Enumerators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000135-SW1):

```
// Don't forget to actually create the mutable array
NSMutableArray * sixLetterWords = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for( NSString * word in allLinedStrings ){
    if( [word length] == 6 ) [sixLetterWords addObject:word];
}
```

and [blocks-based enumeration](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Enumerators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000135-SW3) with [`enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-SW19):

```
NSMutableArray * sixLetterWords = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[allLinedStrings enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id word, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * stop){
    if( [(NSString *)word length] == 6 ) [sixLetterWords addObject:word];
 }];
```

There is also the possibility to [filter the array](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BAJJDBEB):

```
NSArray * sixLetterWords = [allLinedStrings filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"length == 6"
```

Note that this last option gives you an autoreleased array -- if you want to keep it around, you must retain it. With any of these, you no longer have to worry about the array length or explicit indexing; it is handled for you by the array. [Fast enumeration](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocFastEnumeration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH18) is also, as its name indicates, *faster* than a plain `for` loop.

The method that you used to read the text file into your string, `stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:`, is not `new` or `alloc`, nor does it begin with `copy` or `mutableCopy`; therefore, according to [Cocoa memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH27-SW3), you do not own it and do not have to release it. (And if you want it to stick around past the end of the current method, you will need to retain it.)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to release your text file since it will be autoreleased.

EDIT:

You need to alloc and init you NsMutableArray...

```
NSMutableArray* sixLetterWords = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

I had the for loop bit wrong, you had it right the first time.

Comment: Tried this out, does not have compile errors but it stops the app when it gets there, specifically on the line `[sixLetterWords addObject:word];` saying "Thread 1: Program received signal: EXC_BAD_ACCESS".

Comment: The first part of this answer is incorrect. i < wordcount (as in the original code) goes from 0 to i - 1, which is correct. i < wordcount - 1 goes from 0 to wordcount - 2, and will skip the last word.

Comment: Ahh there we go! After that edit, it worked. Lol, I didn't get to alloc and init my array because I was following this tutorial: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Objective-C_Array_Objects#Inserting_Elements_into_an_Array Thanks again!

Comment: Yep, it should not be wordcount - 1.  The OP's version was correct.  And I have no idea what the StrLength function is -- I'd just use `[word length]`.

Comment: Yeah, I'll admit to having quickly given that answer.  Without the actual error, i saw "for loop throwing an error" and jumped to Index out of bounds >.<

Answer (score 0):

Without wanting to blow my own trumpet, the [CMFunctionalAdditions](https://github.com/cmowforth/CMFunctionalAdditions) framework can do this more cleanly and concurrently :)

```
NSArray* sixLetterWords = [allLinedStrings filterWithPredicate:^BOOL(NSString* str) {
    return [str length] == 6;
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your work! You should really put a prefix on your category method names, though. Also, this method's name is awfully similar to the built-in [`filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BAJJDBEB), which takes an `NSPredicate` object rather than a block.

Comment: You're right, for all but the largest collections or most complicated predicates, filderedArrayUsingPredicate is the easiest solution. I assume it's only a matter of time before Apple get this running concurrently too.

Comment: I was only talking about the names, not the implementations. Whenever you add a category to a framework class, you have to be sure that Apple will never add a method whose name is the same as one of yours; the conventional way to do that is with a prefix: `CM_filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`.

Comment: Yeah tbh I was just going to call it select instead :)